# Hyper cannot find Server module

Tags: http, rust, hyper

I'm writing a "hello world" HTTP server with Hyper, however I am not able to find the `Server` and `rt` modules when trying to import them.

When invoking `cargo run`, then I see this error message:

```
26 |     let server = hyper::Server::bind(&addr).serve(router);
   |                         ^^^^^^ could not find `Server` in `hyper`
```

I must be missing something obvious about Rust and Hyper. What I am trying to do is writing something **as dry/simple as possible** with just the HTTP layer and some basic routes. I would like to include as little as possible 3rd party dependencies e.g avoiding Tokio which I think involves async behavior, but I am not sure about the context as I am new to Rust.

Looks like I must use futures, so I included this dependency and perhaps futures only work with the `async` reserved word (which I am not sure if it comes from Tokio or Rust itself).

What confuses me is that in the Hyper examples I do see imports like `use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};`, so that `Server` thing must be there, somewhere.

These are the dependencies in `Cargo.toml`:

```
hyper = "0.14.12"
serde_json = "1.0.67"
futures = "0.3.17"
```

This is the code in `main.rs`:

```rust
use futures::future;
use hyper::service::service_fn;
use hyper::{Body, Method, Response, StatusCode};
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
    let router = || {
        service_fn(|req| match (req.method(), req.uri().path()) {
            (&Method::GET, "/foo") => {
                let mut res = Response::new(
                    Body::from(json!({"message": "bar"}).to_string())
                );
                future::ok(res)
            },
            (_, _) => {
                let mut res = Response::new(
                    Body::from(json!({"content": "route not found"}).to_string())
                );
                *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::NOT_FOUND;
                future::ok(res)
            }
        })
    };

    let addr = "127.0.0.1:8080".parse::<std::net::SocketAddr>().unwrap();
    let server = hyper::Server::bind(&addr).serve(router); // <== this line fails to compile
    // hyper::rt::run(server.map_err(|e| {
    //     eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    // }));
}
```

How do I make the code above compile and run?

Comment: `hyper::server::Server`?? https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.12/hyper/server/index.html

Answer (score 5):

According to [documentation](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.12/hyper/server/index.html), you are missing one module namespace in your call `hyper::server::Server`:

```rust
let server = hyper::server::Server::bind(&addr).serve(router)
```

In order to use `server` you need to activate the [feature flag](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.12/hyper/index.html#optional-features) in cargo:

```
hyper = { version = "0.14.12", features = ["server"] }
```

Comment: "could not find `server` in `hyper`". Weird. Am I supposed to include any hidden dependency - is `hyper = "0.14.12"` enough?

Comment: OK, and now the compiler is saying "could not find `Server` in `server`". No idea what is going on :(

Comment: `bind` is supported on (crate features http1 or http2) and crate feature tcp only. → add those to the feature flags.

Comment: Although there's something missing in the docs: the whole `Server` struct is only available on feature `tcp`, but this is not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Had to add all the 3 of them: `hyper = { version = "0.14.12", features = ["http1", "server", "tcp"] }`. However now there's an issue with the `router` not implementing a Trait or something, but I haven't seen any doc or example providing a router much more complex than what I wrote above: "the trait `for<'a> Service<&'a AddrStream>` is not implemented for `[closure@src/main.rs:7:18: 23:6]`"